# Does memory of Parent type of a Nested Type Exist on Heap?

Tags: c#, oop

I have been reading about nested types in c# and I have just a general question about where they live in memory. As nested types behave like static members or namespaces where you access the type and create an instance of the type as follows:

```
Container.Nested nest = new Container.Nested();

public class Container
{
    public class Nested
    {
        private Container? parent;

        public Nested()
        {
        }
        public Nested(Container parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

This is from the bottom of the c# documentation on nested types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types

now this nest object is an instance of the Container.Nested class which is a reference type so the object reference is on the stack and actual data is on the heap. Would the Container class not be in memory at all at this time only a member of the Container class is in heap memory? We are creating an instance of a member of a class but the parent class itself is not instantiated so basically we just have an object of the Container.Nested on the heap?

Comment: Types don't exist on the managed heap. They're code, the heap is for data.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Yes, so essentially the nest object (data) in this example is on the managed heap but a Container object doesn't exist?

Comment: Nesting types has 2 effects: 1) it scopes the name of the nested type to the container, which looks static-like but isn't actually static, and 2) it confers access to members of the container that wouldn't be available to a non-nested type because the nested type is a member of the container. Otherwise, *it's just another type*.

Comment: If you don't see a `new` statement, there is no new object.

Comment: Interesting @madreflection , So what I am gathering here that an object of the "Container" type does not exist at all here. Only an object of the Container.Nested type is on the heap?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: And if you create an instance of the container type, none of the memory allocated for it involves the nested type. (The same is not true in Java, if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: @madreflection Awesome! They are like completely different objects then. Such weird behavior lol.

Comment: Right. That's why I noted the two effects that nesting has.  There are very narrow cases where a nested type is useful. Don't use them unless you understand those effects and need both.

Comment: Once you understand them fully, they're not weird. There's a lot of very intelligent thought behind it.

Comment: I'd argue it's Java's behaviour that's strange, because it means some types behave differently based on where they are declared.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: I'd have to agree with that.

Answer (score 3):

Nested types are purely organisational; given a type `Foo` and a nested type `Foo.Bar` there is no *instance* relationship between them beyond that which you create yourself. Creating a `Bar` does not mean you have also created an associated `Foo` instance - `Foo` could be `static`, `abstract class`, or even `interface` (runtime dependent).

> now this nest object is an instance of the `Container.Nested` class which is a reference type so the object reference is on the stack and actual data is on the heap.

The object reference can be anywhere (heap or stack), but yes the actual contents of the `Container.Nested` instance are most likely on the heap. In reality, the heap and stack are implementation details, and it usually isn't useful to worry too much about where things are unless you *really really* need to know.

> Would the `Container` class not be in memory at all at this time only a member of the `Container` class is in heap memory?

The *class itself* (the metadata, executable code, etc) is in a separate chunk of memory; *instances* of the class may be on the heap, but in this case there is no `Container` instance created *unless you do that yourself* (to use the second constructor that takes an instance).

> We are creating an instance of a member of a class but the parent class itself is not instantiated so basically we just have an object of the `Container.Nested` on the heap?

Yes, basically; unless you do it yourself, i.e. `new Container.Nested(new Container())`, in which case you'll have one of each.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from many people learning Java before C#.